# I cant get a linux computer from my devices that are signed in my google account and not me

Tags: scam

I was scammed and hacked. I called a hotline that said Facebook help getting unlocked from account and was directed to install an app that allowed the operator to see my screen and navigate to my cash app and buy bitcoin and sent it to some woman named Donna and they are still available to say they are me in a computer but not.

Comment: sorry to hear you were tricked, and i hope your losses aren't high - something you can do at this point is disconnect your computer from the internet, and report the incident to your bank (cash app?) and maybe law enforcement - it's unlikely that anything will come of it, but you never know - maybe the purchase can be reversed? as far as cleaning your computer goes, no advice can be given because you haven't mentioned what software, operating system, etc. that you use. do you have a tech-savvy friend that you can contact? you should also change all of your important passwords

Comment: You need to change all your passwords and enable MFA. This type of technical support is not that type of thing we do here. You need someone who can walk you through everything step-by-step.

Comment: Thank you but I've been on phones only and I'm signed in Asa Linux x86_64 and I'm not but I wrote down the imei s of my samsung that is somehow paired with someone else's computer